# Databricks, AzureCredentialNotFoundException

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I have a High Concurency cluster with Active Directory integration turned on. Runtime: Latest stable (Scala 2.11), Python: 3.

I've mounted Azure Datalake and when I want to read the data, always the first time after cluster start I get:

```
com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.adl.AzureCredentialNotFoundException: Could not find ADLS Gen1 Token
```

When I rerun it works fine. I read data in the following way:

```
df = spark.read.option("inferSchema","true").option("header","true").json(path)
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Thanks!
Tomek

Comment: You may refer this article, which explains about the same issue: https://kb.azuredatabricks.net/data-sources/access-adls1-from-sparklyr.html

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can only run the command using a high concurrency cluster. If you've attached your notebook to a standard cluster, the command won't work.

Comment: The question starts with "I have a High Concurrency cluster ...".

Comment: Yes but he may not have attached the notebook to the high concurrency cluster.